# Where joomfish store translation content?

Tags: joomla, phpmyadmin, joomla1.5, joomfish

That look easy but...
I'm trying to find the translation content but 
In which table in phpmyadmin ? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In J1.5, the tables included "jf" in the name - jos_jf_content.

If you can determine the right table, this SQL should get you started:

```
SELECT
    j.`introtext`,j.`fulltext`      
    jf.`introtext`,jf.`fulltext`      
FROM jos_content AS j
INNER JOIN jmo_jfcontent AS jf ON (j.id = jf.id)
WHERE (j.alias ='branchen')
```

It wont run as is, because I don't know the table structure or column names, but it should be relatively easy to adapt when you identify the table and the primary key.

Comment: Thanks again! I looked at it, but I do not see any alias or article id, which column?

Comment: We no longer have it installed, so I can't check for you, but as I recall, it was very close to the jos_content table, with additional columns for language.  What I'd do is turn on site debugging for a moment, display a page that uses that table, and look at the SQL statements that Joomla executes - it will be there.

Comment: There is a jos_jcontent table

Comment: Sorry, there is a jos_content table but i do not see any id or alias, is there a way to search an translation alias= 'branchen' in ALL table started with jmo_ ?

Comment: I don't have anything to refer to, but that sounds like the right table.  I can only recall that while jos_content is the Joomla table for all articles, there should be a table called something like "jos_jcontent" that contains all the translated equivalents to what is in jos_content.  When Joomla goes to display the article from jos_content, the jomfish plugin intercepts that, and gets the translated text from jos_jcontent.  How they're joined, I can't be sure, but would be surprise if it wasn't by the id column.

Comment: Identify the table with the translated content, then it is just a matter of a SQL statement that JOINS on the id (and maybe language).

Comment: Ok that doesn't sound as easy as writing a query to select an article with its alias from the defaut language. I m trying to find the transition content... Well hidden!

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult at all - but you have to identify the table, and the primary key - see my updated answer for a SQL statement to get started with.

Comment: you are a wonderdul person, tanks a lot, I ll try To do that, I m still searching the translation into this JFcontent  (I tried to use the search feature but apparently it can't find the alias 'branchen' I ll look again one by one. Thanks a lot, such a nice person you are!

Comment: Ho gosh it is embarrassing! I did not find anything bcs I was looking in "structure" and not in browse! Ok that makes more sense now! I ll try... I should look like a grand ma using a microwave!

Comment: Well, happy to help, hope my answer was part of the solution :)

Comment: Do not feel oblige to reply, but I m confuse with that   jos_content.introtext  Is it a kind of shortcut to attach .introtext to the table or are you talking of a table that ll be named "jos_content.introtext" (my table have no ".xxx")?

Comment: Joomla stores its articles in the table jos_content.  Each article has two "parts", the column *introtext* is typically the first paragraph, and the column *fulltext*,which is the remainder of the article.  Sometimes everything is contained in *introtext*, but that's up to the author.

Comment: Ok! but my tables are like that jmo_content , jmo_jfcontent , (introtext is a row inside it I do not have any table with a "." on it. I made the start and I am trying to understand the strange code after that (INNER JOIN ... What a challenge!)

Comment: `SELECT introtext,fulltext
    
FROM jos_content,
   , jos_jfcontent. Working on the rest!`

Comment: Just altered my answer to match more closely to your tables - though i don't know what the actual Joomfish columns are.

Comment: the base of the code :

SELECT introtext,fulltext FROM jos_content WHERE alias='branchen' -OR IF THERE IS NOTHING-
 SELECT jos_jfcontent WHERE reference_field='alias' AND value='branchen'

Comment: I did not explain what I wanted to do: 
I would like a single code that I ll copy past and only change the alias of it. (Eg: If I  ask variable='branchen' it should look in both table jmo_content & jmo_jfcontent and find the right article in the right table).  

-------------------
branchfr ID=127
I fund branchfr in jmo_jfcontent BUT the ID=127 In this table is ok only if reference_field='alias' et value='branchen'

_jfcontent column: reference_field  value
 _content column: ID

Comment: If you paste the CREATE TABLE code of your tables into your question, I'll see if I can come up with what you need.

Comment: Ha ha! Such a gentleman you are! I finally cut it into 2 peaces (fr + en) and it works beautifully, I own you my first beloved peace of code! Very please to meet you GDP! thanks for your wonderful patience, I wish you a colorful day! (I m this one 20000km.com creating a new political movement --> working on its website!)